# Load incremental data from salesforce to azure synpase using azure data factory

Tags: salesforce, azure-data-factory

I wanted to load one table incremental load from salesforce to azure synpase. Since in mapping data flow connector salesforce won't available. How can we achieve using Azure data factory tool.

Comment: Can copy activity of ADF be considered? Load Incremental data based on watermark?

Comment: Adf copy I will be using but it will do only bulk load, for watermark any link you have in terms of salesforce and synapse. Within Azuresql watermark link I have.